# Visual Basic bind checkbox check state to application setting at runtime

Tags: vb.net

I would like to add a checkbox control to a form at runtime. I can accomplish that, but I would also like to bind the "Checked" property to an application setting that is already created.
The code I have so far is below. When I run an exception is raised: "Cannot bind to the property or column Checked on the DataSource"
What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim CurrentCheckBox As New CheckBox
Dim TableColumn As Integer = 4
Dim TableRow As Integer = 13

CurrentCheckBox.Name = "MyCheckbox"
CurrentCheckBox.Text = ""
CurrentCheckBox.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Top
CurrentCheckBox.AutoSize = True
CurrentCheckBox.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Checked", 
My.Settings.MyCheckboxIsChecked, "Checked"))

MyTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(CurrentCheckBox, TableColumn, TableRow)
```

Comment: I guess the `Binding` should be `New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Checked", 
My.Settings, "MyCheckboxIsChecked")`...

Comment: Your `Binding` constructor is redundant. The `Add` method will accept the same arguments directly. In situations like this, the best option is to do the same thing in the designer, i.e. add a `CheckBox` and bind it to s setting, then see what code is generated. You can then use the same pattern, cleaning it up if appropriate.